# How many storms are happening on Earth at a given moment?

Tags: earth-system, storms

How many different storms, thunderstorms, snow storms, hurricanes, typhoons, what have you, are happening in the Earth our planet at any given point in time. Furthermore, I imagine they are over the water mostly, is this true?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, what ever number someone comes up with is going to be just a guess, and worse, the _actual_ number is going to constantly change.

Comment: what is a storm for you is not a storm for me,what you call a thunderstorm-snow storm-rain storm have nothing to do with a storm unless the wind speed is at storm force or abowe storm force https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaufort_scale

Comment: An answer for thunderstorms: "Worldwide, there are an estimated 16 million thunderstorms each year, and at any given moment, there are roughly 2,000 thunderstorms in progress." From https://www.nssl.noaa.gov/education/svrwx101/thunderstorms/ (no idea how they got these numbers)